# Build Path Issue

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

In Eclipse we have a project where we reference an external jar in the build path. When I upload my project to the repository and my colleagues check it out, the build path looks for the jar file in the same place. One of us uses a Mac so doesn't even have a C: drive and my other colleague has a different partition containing the jar, so it always breaks.

How do we fix this issue? Ideally the jar file would be included as part of the project but it seems that the svn commit doesn't include the referenced library.

Thanks

Comment: just a rough it may work.Go to project properties.Inside build path add any library and press ok.Then run it.If it will run then remove that library after running. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you use a build tool (maven, ant/ivy, gradle, etc) along with a repository manager (such as nexus or archiva), depending on what you use to build your project. These store libraries in a central location(s) and then users get the libraries from there.

In eclipse, when you include your .classpath file in the checkin, you will have the issues you are describing, since the .classpath file will contain the path to the file, and then you all must have the files in the same locations. A workaround for this is to create a "lib" directory and put all of the libraries in there. Each of the users can then add all of the libraries in that directory to their path (but do not checkin the .classpath file). This is an older way of doing things before the concept of dependency managers.

Answer (score 1):

Add the jar as part of the project (say in a lib folder in your project) and commit it to svn.

Comment: Concur, maven or some other DCS would be better solution

Answer (score 0):

Start using Maven, to resolve your dependencies. 
Worst case : Commit the external jar into another project called MyProjectDependencies

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) to avoid incident like this and to get many others pluses. 
You can find many guides on `maven`, for example [this one](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html).
Eclipse has integration with `maven`.

Answer (score 0):

1.) Check in JAR in a directory inside the project.

2.) Use Maven (or something similar) to manage your dependencies.

3.) Create a User Library referencing the JAR and refer to it this way in your project. Each user will need to create the User Library in their install of Eclipse, but it sounds like you're already doing something similar by referencing the library externally anyway.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use a dependency management tool like Maven, a simple solution in your case would be to use an Eclipse Classpath Variable. All projects can reference the variable, but it will have a different value for each developer.

Set up a Classpath Variable with:

- Right click on the Project, select Project Properties
- Click Add Variable
- Configure Variables
- New...
- Name the variable and point to a Folder

Now commit your .classpath file. The variable will be referenced in the .classpath. Each developer can configure to their particular directory, and Extend the variable to a specific jar file.